# Gtk.Entry autocomplete?

Tags: gtk

I am trying to do something like this picture, with a GTK Entry:

[image: auto completion]

Basically, what I want is that, if the user types "keyb" (white text), the Entry will suggest "oard" (gray text) because the word "keyboard" is in a list of words, that I will provide.

I have tried the SetCompletion() function, but that opens a drop down with suggestions, and I guess I'll go with that if there is no other way. I have tried searching for it, but it is hard when you don't know the GTK word for this "technique". Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
EntryCompletion.set_inline_completion(True)
```

When creating an Gtk Entry Completion

Comment: Awesome, I only looked for properties/functions on the Entry, not the EntryCompletion...